# Share the database with another person in same network

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am a newbie to the database topic. I need to create a database and share the database to another person in my office so the other person can also create/delete tables in the same database. I created the database using My sql server 5.6 and using DbVisualizer as database management tool. Could anyone please tell me what should I do to share my database to another person? or is it better to use some other database management system like Oracle db?

P.S : I tried searching in the internet and I could not find an appropriate answers.

Comment: You're very unlikely to get an answer to this question. It doesn't fit the site very well. And honestly, why would you ever use a database just to share data between two people? Try OneNote / EverNote / a shared excel file / any other product intended for that.

Comment: I am creating an application with database and two other persons also works on the same application and want to  access the database to create or delete tables in the database

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have firewall allow the IP of the client.

In your my.cnf make sure you have the port listening on the correct IP.
Look for bind-address and change it to "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" to open it for all interfaces.

Then add a user access to the database.

```
shell> mysql --user=root mysql
mysql> GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO client@192.168.1.50 IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

change 192.168.1.50 to appropriate IP address.

Comment: I am using mysql server 5.6 and i could not find my.cnf file.

Comment: Usually it's located in /etc/my.cnf